# Error in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need someone to help me with finding the error in my sql query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE confirm(IN bookingID INT, OUT status VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
DECLARE numberOfPass INT;
DECLARE contactStatus VARCHAR(30);
SET numberOfPass = (SELECT count(*) FROM passenger WHERE passenger.Booking = bookingID);
SET contactStatus = (SELECT contact FROM booking WHERE booking.Id = bookingID);
IF numberOfPass <> (SELECT numberOfSeats FROM booking WHERE booking.Id  = bookingID)) THEN SET status = "Passenger information missing";
ELSE IF ISNULL(contactStatus) THEN SET status ="Contact missing for booking";
ELSE SET status = "OK";
END IF;
END;
```

I get the following error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ') THEN SET status = "Passenger information
>   missing"; ELSE IF ISNULL(contactStatu' at line 7

What could be the error ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You've got an extra parentheses at

```
IF numberOfPass <> (SELECT numberOfSeats FROM booking WHERE booking.Id  = bookingID))
```

Answer (score 2):

- use `ELSEIF`
- remove extra parenthesis

full query,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE confirm(IN bookingID INT, OUT status VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
    DECLARE numberOfPass INT;
    DECLARE contactStatus VARCHAR(30);
    SET numberOfPass = (SELECT count(*) FROM passenger WHERE passenger.Booking = bookingID);
    SET contactStatus = (SELECT contact FROM booking WHERE booking.Id = bookingID);
    IF numberOfPass <> (SELECT numberOfSeats FROM booking WHERE booking.Id  = bookingID) THEN 
        SET status = "Passenger information missing";
    ELSEIF ISNULL(contactStatus) THEN 
        SET status ="Contact missing for booking";
    ELSE 
        SET status = "OK";
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

- [See IF Syntax <sup>MySQL Doc</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't knew that I should use ELSEIF.

Answer (score 1):

extra ) in ur code...

```
                                                                                    !!!
 IF numberOfPass <> (SELECT numberOfSeats FROM booking WHERE booking.Id  = bookingID))
```